# Transit visa policies for Frankfurt and Colombo

Tags: visas, transit, germany, connecting-flights, sri-lanka

I'm an Indian citizen holding a US student visa. I'm looking for flight tickets and found one with two connections, one in Sri-Lanka (Colombo) and the other in Germany (Frankfurt).

Do I need Transit Visa for both of these countries ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an US visa, you don't need a transit visa in frankfurt. Srilanka doesn't need transit visa anyways.

You can make this trip without any transit visa, provided it is same ticket and you do not plan to get out of the airport.

Comment: Assuming that the OP is not self-connecting and will stay  in the international transit area of the airport https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ (‘get out of the airport’  doesn’t necessarily  = ‘stay airside’)

Comment: @Traveller I meant no self connect by mentioning the same ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a plan to go out of the airport in Sri Lanka, then you don't have to apply any visa.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an official source for your answer

Comment: Even if you plan to get out, you can get a free transit visa to leave the airport. I myself got it few years back. You may have to escalate to a senior official. Regular on arrival visa is available for Indians. See here - https://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/fees.jsp?locale=en_US